# how to use enumerate() to change a value in a nested list

Tags: python, arrays, enumerate

I have a 2D array from a geotiff file. See the example array below:

```
example_array = [[ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                 [ 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I am attempting to write a program that will change the first number greater than 1 in each nested list to the 'value + 100'.

With the help of others see the below working code snippet:

```
for i, sub_list in enumerate(example_array[1:], start= 1):
 for j, entry in enumerate(sub_list[1:][1:1], start = 1):
        if entry > 1 and j != 1 and j != len(sub_list):
            example_array[i][j] += 100
print(example_array)
```

The above code produces the below incorrect example array where none of the values are changing:

```
incorrect_example_array = [[ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                           [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                           [ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                           [ 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                           [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                           [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I would like to create the following correct example array

```
correct_example_array = [[  0,  1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [ 102, 1,  1, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [  0, 103, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                         [ 104, 1,  1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                         [  0, 105, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                         [  0,  1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: `for j, entry in enumerate(sub_list[1:][1:1], start = 1)` Why are you using a slice of `[1:1]`?  That slice is _guaranteed_ to be empty.  So the second `for` loop never executes, and therefore the innermost code obviously never executes either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop does not need the index; `enumerate` is not needed. You can break the inner loop as soon as a match is found. There is no need to perform any checks on the inner index either.

```py
for l in example_array:
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x > 1:
            l[i] += 100
            break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you have any recommendations if I wanted to manipulate the last value in the list aswell? could I start the for loop from [-1]?

Comment: @Patstro Just change it to `for i, x in reversed([*enumerate(l)])`

Comment: Thank you! Last question: Is there a way to specify a certain list to run the for loop through exclusively? If I hypothetically only wanted to change the first number greater than 1 in the last list in the array. Or is there a resource that you used to provide you with the education to work through this problem for yourself?

Comment: @Patstro Then you only need one loop. Remove the outer loop and use `for i, x in enumerate(example_array[-1]):` and `example_array[-1][i] += 100`

Comment: If there was a reason to manipulate other values within the array, say instead of the first number greater than one if we wanted to change the second number greater than 1 could I add an argument within the if x > 1: to then move around the array relative to the first value greater than 1 that the initial code finds?